# Javascript String Parameter with space doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php

as the title already says I am calling a onclick method in php, but every string with a space in it seems to fail.

php (mysql loop)

```
echo '<img onclick=test("'.$row['name'].'","name'.$row['id'].'") src="blabla.png"/>';
```

javascript

```
function test(vali, id){

   alert(vali); //Maria, Josef (but not "Michael Jackson")
   alert(id); //name23, name28
}
```

As I said if its a string without a space, alert method is getting called and shows the text, however with at least one space nothing happens.

Comment: echo '<img onclick="test('.$row['name'].', name'.$row['id'].')" src="blabla.png"/>'; ?

Comment: @DevNiels prob mainly because name'.$row['id'].' is one value so I have to put it in "" else javascript wont know the id is for example "name12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole onclick handler needs to be quoted. You then need to also HTML-escape the quotes inside it.

```
echo '<img onclick="test(&quot;'.$row['name'].'&quot;,&quot;name'.$row['id'].'&quot;)" src="blabla.png"/>';
```

In the HTML this will then appear as

```
<img onclick="test(&quot;A Name With Spaces&quot;,&quot;name1&quot;)" src="blabla.png"/>
```

And the javascript part is ultimately decoded to

```
test("A Name With Spaces","name1")
```

Comment: ur genius ty :)

Comment: and how would u do this in javascript :)? `.innerHTML="<img onclick=test2('"+vali+"','"+id+"') />";` cause if I replace the single quotes with &quote; it doesnt seem to work for me :/

Comment: In Javascript you quote using backslash, ie: `\"` but you're still not wrapping the onclick handler and really should avoid innerHTML in favour of more modern methods like `var img = new Image(); img.addEventListener('click', someFunction); someElement.appendChild(img)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below

```
<img onclick='test("<?php echo $row['name']; ?>",name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>")' src="blabla.png"/>
```